# Using a variadic template parameter for vectors of tuples failing

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am using g++ 5.2.  Why does this work?

```
void func(std::vector<std::tuple<int>> v)
{
    ...
}

func({ std::make_tuple(1), std::make_tuple(2), std::make_tuple(3) });
```

But this does not?  As they seem logically equivalent to me.

```
template <typename... Args>
void func(std::vector<std::tuple<Args...>> v)
{
    ...
}

func({ std::make_tuple(1), std::make_tuple(2), std::make_tuple(3) });
```

It gives the error:

```
error: could not convert ‘{std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {int}](), std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {int}](), std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {int}]()}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<std::tuple<>, std::allocator<std::tuple<> > >’
func({ std::make_tuple(1), std::make_tuple(2), std::make_tuple(3) });
                                                                   ^
```

Comment: try to remove the `{}` in the second call. It works in the first arg because std::vector can be initialized with an initializer list.

Comment: That would call the function with three arguments, which won't compile because it takes one argument.

Comment: `func({ std::make_tuple(1), std::make_tuple(2), std::make_tuple(3) });` problem is, how do you expect the compiler to know if the initializer list designates a `vector` or a `tuple`?

Comment: ... or a `Foo`, or any other type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'd behave somewhat equivalently if you actually called them with a vector of tuples, but you don't do that.

```
void func(std::vector<std::tuple<int>> v)
```

This has an argument with a known type, and the initializer-list that you use can be converted to that type, so it works. You've said "the function takes type X, and here is an argument convertible to X". The compiler can do that.

```
template <typename... Args>
void func(std::vector<std::tuple<Args...>> v)
```

This function template has to deduce its argument type. But you don't call it with a vector of tuples that would allow it to deduce the tuple element types. You call it with an initializer-list that could be converted to lots of different types (vectors, lists, tuples, or many other  types).  The compiler can't deduce the type of the vector until it converts the initializer-list to that type, but it can't know if the conversion is valid until it knows what type of vector you have, so there's a chicken and egg situation. It can't deduce the type until it does the conversion, but can't do the conversion until it knows the type.

Comment: But it's already an initializer list of tuples, which could be match against the vector's generic signature's parameterized tuples, or not?

Comment: Which vector? How do you match it against the possible constructors for the vector without knowing what kind of vector it is? It's not a `std::initializer_list` of tuples, it's a braced-init-list, and that has no type, it's a syntactical construct, not a type. That braced-init-list can be used to initialize the `std::initializer_list<T>` parameter of the `std::vector<T>::vector(intializer_list<T>)` constructor but only after it knows what `T` is so it can see that constructor exists.

Comment: It would be equally valid for the compiler to deduce `float` or `long` in this case, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation fails because function template arguments cannot be deduced from an initializer list.